# How to create the time entry in NetSuite through API

Tags: time, netsuite

When I try to create a time entry to NetSuite it throwing error as below: 
" 8:00 is not a legal value for {urn:types.core_2018_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}DurationUnit ".  How to enter the hours in TimeEntry. https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_2/schema/record/timeentry.html?mode=package

I have tried with "8:00", "8", "8.00"

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated

Comment: Hours is a Duration which wants a Timespan and a Unit. First of those is a double, the second is a DurationUnit which is just hour. So try "8 hour" or provide both parts separately.

Comment: @Brian it worked. thank you. Also need one more help. 
how to provide "Approved" status for approvalStatus API?  I tired multiple times it takes as approval pending.  Is there any specific value i need to pass in it?

Comment: Add to the question vs asking more in a comment. Normally I would say ask another question but both are related.

Answer (score 0):

Hours is a Duration which wants a Timespan and a Unit. First of those is a double, the second is a DurationUnit which is just hour. So try "8 hour" or provide both parts separately.

approvalStatus is a RecordRef so you would normally provide the InternalId or ExternalId of the status record. The only list of values I could find was for timesheets.

```
INTERNALID  VALUE
1           Open
2           Pending Approval
3           Approved
4           Rejected
```